# React native How to display access token in home page using asyncstorage

Tags: react-native, access-token, asyncstorage

i have stored access_token in asyncstorage,and i get that access_token.now i want to display that access token in home page.if any one know please help me.

```
 async componentDidMount(){

let accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);
console.warn(accessToken);
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false })
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        if(accessToken != null || accessToken == "true"){
            navigate("Home");
        }
        else{
            navigate("Login");
        } 
    },500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do following:

```
 AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN).then(token=>{
     if(token){
     accessToken = token
       // if it is an object
       const key = accessToken.yourKeyName
        navigate("Home", {myKey: key});
    }

}).catch(err=>{
  // handle error
})
```

then on Home page:

```
const {myKey} = this.props.navigation.state.params
```

and show *myKey* in `<Text>`on Home Page.

AsyncStorage returns a promise so you can handle it using .then.